# SQL Query gives wrong output in one argument

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm using sql statement in PHP to get results from a server database.
The Query is executing fine, however I'm getting errors in query results, from one of the arguments (**cardName**) in the SQL statement.

## Search Test Cases Results:

- **IF** (cardNumber= '', cardName != empty, cardOwner ='' )
  **Result=>** Returns all records in table, regardless if cardName value exists on database or not.
- **IF** cardName + (cardNumber OR cardOwner ) search filter
  **Result =>** returns more records than actually anticipated.
- **IF** cardNumber, CardName and cardOwner are all not empty
  **Result=>** accurate result shown in all scenarios
- cardNumber and cardOwner gives correct results in all tested scenarios (unless in combination with cardName)

---

**Data Get and Search Code**

```php
    /*...........Get Values............*/

    if($_POST['srch_cardNumber_txt']){
        $cardNumber = $_POST['srch_cardNumber_txt'];
    }
    else{$cardNumber="";}

    if($_POST['srch_cardName_txt']){
        $cardName = $_POST['srch_cardName_txt'];            // _/
    }
    else{$cardName = "";}                                   // _/

    if($_POST['srch_cardOwner_txt']){
        $cardOwner = $_POST['srch_cardOwner_txt'];
    }
    else{ $cardOwner="";}

    echo "Filters:: Card Number: ".$cardNumber." -- Card Name: ".$cardName.
        " -- Card Owner: ".$cardOwner."<br>";

 if(!empty($cardName) or !empty($cardNumber) or !empty($cardOwner)  ){
    include_once("db_connect.php");

     if ( mysqli_connect_error()){
         die('Connect Error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
         }

         else{
                 //.............Search Pseudo Code........
/*                      SELECT *        
                         FROM Table
                         WHERE (f1  = '' or c1 = f1)
                           AND (f2  = '' or c2 = f2)
                           AND (f3 = '' or c3 = f3)
                           AND (f4 = '' or c4= f4)
*/

                 $SELECT = "SELECT *
                                FROM cards
                                WHERE (? = '' or cardNumber = ? )
                                    AND (? = '' or cardName = ? )
                                    AND (? = '' or cardOwner = ? )
                                ";
                                                        /*ERROR: Searching only cardName returns all cards data - cardName filter can work in combination with additional filters*/


                // if All values are equal to null, then  retrun false / end search
                if($cardName ='' AND $cardNumber ='' AND $cardOwner='')
                {
                    echo "Search fields are all empty<br>";s
                    return False;
                }
                 //.........Prepare statement.....
                 $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
                 $stmt->bind_param("iissss",$cardNumber,$cardNumber,$cardName,$cardName,$cardOwner, $cardOwner);            //Works with HardCoded cardName value
                 $stmt-> execute();
                 $stmt->store_result();
                 $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

                 if($rnum == 0){
                     $stmt->close();                     
                     echo "No card records found on given search inputs <br>";                   
                     }
                     else {                      
                         $stmt->bind_result($cardNumber,$cardName,$cardOwner);                       
                     }
//                  $conn->close();
             }   
     }
     else {
         echo "no data entered for search";
         die();
         }       

?>
```

---

**Data Ouput code**

```php
                <?php  
                if( $rnum > 0 ){
                    echo "Number of records found: ".$rnum."<br>";
                    while($stmt->fetch()) {
                             echo "A card is found with Card #".$cardNumber."<br>".$cardName."<br>".$cardOwner."<br>------------<br>";
                    } 
                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();
                }else{
                    echo "No records found<br>";
                }
                     ?>
```

### Data Images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlStj.jpg

Comment: In the statement `if($cardName ='' AND $c...` - this is doing an assignment to all values and not a test.

Comment: this should havebeen much easier with pdo, you basically need dynamic bind param for this case

Comment: @NigelRen  oh wow - I didn't realize this! this is a real rookie mistake- thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error after 48 row:

```
if($cardName ='' AND $cardNumber ='' AND $cardOwner='')
{
    echo "Search fields are all empty<br>";s
    return False;
}
```

You are checking values, not setting. Use double equals (==).
It should be:

```
if ($cardName =='' AND $cardNumber =='' AND $cardOwner=='') {
    echo "Search fields are all empty<br>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed out on this error - 
thanks for pointing it out!